# order by and click is not working in ng-repeat angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

ng-repeat to show data from database but my order by predicate,reverse functionality and click is not working

```
<div ng-repeat="shipment in sortedShipments">
  <div ng-click="show_shipment($index,shipment.shipment_id)" ng-class="{selected_trip: $index === currentShipment}">
     <div>{{shipment.from_location}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is fetching records from database HTTP request and sorting code

```
$http.get(url+'/get-shipments').success(function(data){
  $scope.shipments = data;
  $scope.sortedShipments = $filter('orderBy')($scope.shipments, 'predicate', true);
  $scope.currentShipment = 0;
  $scope.sortType  = 'shipment_id';
  $scope.predicate = 'created_at';
  $scope.reverse = false;
});
```

for click functionality i have two button to move to next shipment div using selected index and previous button

```
<a class="" ng-click="next($event)"  href="#">next</a>
<a class="" ng-click="previous($event)"  href="#">previous</a>
```

and angular js code is

```
$scope.next = function($event) {
  if ($scope.currentShipment < $scope.sortedShipments.length - 1) {
       $scope.currentShipment++;
       $('.selected_trip').click();
  }
};
$scope.previous = function($event) {
  if ($scope.currentShipment > 0) {
      $scope.currentShipment--;
      $('.selected_trip').click();
  }
};
```

the problem is it goes to next item add selected_trip class on it but i also want to trigger a click on selected class so that it can call this function on the selected row `ng-click="show_shipment($index,shipment.shipment_id)"`
but currently `$('.selected_trip').click();` this is giving me error 
i have also tried this to

```
document.querySelector('.selected_trip').click();
```

here is show_shipment method

```
 $scope.show_shipment = function(index,id) {
        $scope.setSelected(index); 
        $http.get(url+'/get-shipments/'+id).success(function(data){
           $scope.to_location = data[0]['to_location'];
        })
})
```

Here is my code for order by which is not working when i started to use the $filter option in js

```
 $scope.order = function(predicate) {
      $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
      $scope.predicate = predicate;
    };
```

Comment: You should not do this `$('.selected_trip').click();`. This will not guarantied to work, as well as `document.querySelector('.selected_trip').click();`.

Comment: @dfsq then what should i use

Comment: Is show_shipment a function defined in your controller?

Comment: yes it is a function which show the data of selected shipment in the other tab

Answer (score 0):

You should use `angular.element` and `trigger` method:

So this: `$('.selected_trip').click();`

Becomes: `angular.element('.selected_trip').trigger('click');`

And it should work.

**EDIT**:

You should also use `$timeout` as workaround because you are in a `$digest` yet and you cannot call `$apply` again and this is why you get those errors.

I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/p1yuockj/1/) to explain you the use of `$timeout`:

```
app.controller('dummy', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.test = function () {
        $timeout(function() {
            angular.element('.selected_trip').trigger('click');
        }, 0, false);
    }

    $scope.show_shipment = function () {
        $scope.clicked = "hello world";
    };
});
```

More info here: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=$apply

Comment: sorry for the late reply but it is not working it is giving me this error 
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply
    at Error (native)

Comment: That could be a problem with the `show_shipment()` method but you didn't post it

Comment: Try to do only a `console.log('hello')` in `show_shipment` and it should work

Comment: i have posted the show_shipment() method in answer when the page by defaults loads it prints the hello in console but when we trigger the click using angualr it give me 3 errors in console
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply

Comment: Thanks @Michelem but also my order by is not working as i have asked for helped for that to in my question could you please kindly help me on that part to why it is not working

Comment: i have also updated my question added the order_by code in question so that you can have a look at the problem in detail Kindly please help me on this